# Add an address to the wallet CLI with a payment ID

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, address

I've tried to add an address to the address book with

```
address_book add xxx yyy recipient
```

where `xxx` is the address, `yyy` the payment ID and `recipient` is a description for that address but the wallet ignores the payment ID and use `yyy recipient` as a description.

How can I add an address with a payment ID and a description to the address book?

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is (see the emphasis):

```
address_book [(add (<address> [pid <long or short payment id>])|<integrated address> [<description possibly with whitespaces>])|(delete <index>)]
                               ^^^
```

So you need to identify the payment id with `pid` - in your case it would look like:

```
address_book xxx pid yyy recipient
```